# AngularJS component use N times dynamically

Tags: angularjs, components

I am new in AngularJS and I am using component in my module.
I have module:

```
angular.module("reviewApp",[]).component("applicantDetails",{
   templateUrl : '../comp/Applicant_Details_Fields.html',
   controller : function($scope){...}
});
```

At this moment I can use my component from HTML code like this

`<applicant-details></applicant-details>`
But now I need to change it to be more flexible. Depending on given N value it must add that component in the HTML N times.
For example N = 3; then it must dynamically add in my html code 3 times

`<applicant-details></applicant-details>`

Can I achieve this functionality with AngularJS with simple way? I tried several ways, and searched many times, but I couldn't find how to do this.
Even I tried to add that tags with JavaScript, but it understands only empty tags without content.

Comment: Did you try with ng-repeat?

Comment: In ng-repeat I have to add my component in the array of an object and then process it in ng-repeat, but  I couldn't add my component as an object.

Comment: @R.O. it's like a for loop, simply have `<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]"><applicant-details /></div>` to repeat it 3 times, replace `[1,2,3]` with a dynamic array, the length of which can be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of simple looping in angular js

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="ctrlParent">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber) track by $index"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myOtherNumber) track by $index"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('ctrlParent',function($scope){
    $scope.myNumber = 5;
    $scope.myOtherNumber = 10;
    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);   
    }
});
```

check output:http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/cHQLH/

Comment: `ng-repeat` expects an object or array. It will not work by using a number.

Comment: in this case it shows correctly, but I have a checkbox in my component, and when I click on one of the checkbox it is checking only first one. How can I give them unique Id's to be separate from each other?So when I click onone of the checkbox, it will check only that one?

Comment: can you please post some HTML code here? so I can do some stuff or change on that.

Comment: I found the answer, I just need to add in my component checkbox      
 id="name_{{$id}}" and <lable for="name_{{$id}}"></lable> where $id is the unique scope id provided by $rootScope for every child scope.Thanks for your help.

Comment: My reputation is not so high to mark it as useful, i tried